# Woocommerce - phone mask on login page

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, mask, registration, custom-fields

i use script for phone mask on chekout page.
On chekout page i used this `if (is_checkout())`
I add this mask on adress page in my account use this `if (is_account_page())`

I need help to add this mask on registration page too.
I create custom field on registration page but I don't know what to use instead `if (is_checkout())` to add mask on my new custom (phone) filed on registartion page

Mask

```
// mask
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masked_input');
function masked_input() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('masked_input', get_site_url().'/wp-content/JS/jquery.maskedinput.min.js', array('jquery'));
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'masked_script', 999);
    }
}
 
function masked_script() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|9]";
$("#billing_phone").mask("+998 (h999999999");
    });
</script>

<?php
    }
}
```

Custom field on reg page

```
// Add extra registration fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'woo_add_extra_registration_fields', 20 );
function woo_add_extra_registration_fields() {?>


    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required"> *</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
    </p>


    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}

// Validate require additional registration fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'woo_extra_registration_fields_validation', 20, 3 );
function woo_extra_registration_fields_validation( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    $error  = '<strong>' . __( 'Error', $domain ) . '</strong>: ';



    // Billing Phone field
    if ( isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) )
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', $error . __( 'Phone is required!.', $domain ) );


    return $validation_errors;
}

// Save extra registration fields data
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'woo_save_extra_registration_fields_data', 20, 1 );
function woo_save_extra_registration_fields_data( $customer_id ) {

    // Billing Phone Field
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: the conditional `is_account_page()` works also for user login/registration page named "My account" that uses `my-account` slug in the URL.

Comment: Oh thanks, so the problem is that the mask does not work for the new field in something else, maybe there is another way to attach the script to this custom field

Answer (score 0):

LoicTheAztec big thanks, after your hint I started looking for the problem in a different way and found the answer

Just change this `$("#billing_phone").mask("+998 (h999999999");` on this `$("#reg_billing_phone").mask("+998 (h99)9999999");`

```
// mask
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masked_input');
function masked_input() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('masked_input', get_site_url().'/wp-content/JS/jquery.maskedinput.min.js', array('jquery'));
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'masked_script', 999);
    }
}
 
function masked_script() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|9]";
$("#reg_billing_phone").mask("+998 (h99)9999999");
    });
</script>

<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As WooCommerce uses now, more custom tables should need something a bit different when saving the billind_phone.

Also, you can make it work for checkout and My account registration, with the following:

```php
// mask
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masked_input');
function masked_input() {
    // Only on checkout and on My account registration
    if ( ( is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('masked_input', get_site_url().'/wp-content/JS/jquery.maskedinput.min.js', array('jquery'));

        if ( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
            add_action( 'wp_footer', 'masked_script', 999);
        }
    }
}

function masked_script() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|9]";
        $('[name=billing_phone]').mask("+998 (h99)9999999");
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

And for saving the billing phone from registration:

```php
// Save extra registration fields data
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'woo_save_extra_registration_fields_data', 20, 1 );
function woo_save_extra_registration_fields_data( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { // Billing Phone Field
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id ); // get an instance of customer object
        $customer->update_meta_data( 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']) );
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

Tested and works on both checkout and My account registration.